# Sort a string, sort of

Tags: code-golf, string, sorting

If you sort a string you'll typically get something like:

```
         ':Iaaceeefggghiiiiklllllmnnooooprrssstttttuuyyyy
```

<sub>Yes, that was the first sentence sorted.</sub>

As you can see, there are a lot of repeated characters, `aa`, `eee`, `ttttt`, 9 spaces and so on.

If we add `128` to the ASCII-value of the first duplicate, `256` to the second, `384` to the third and so on, sort it again and output the new string (modulus 128 to get the same characters back) we get the string:

```
 ':Iacefghiklmnoprstuy aegilnorstuy egilosty iloty lt
```

<sub>(Note the single leading space and the 4 trailing spaces).</sub>

The string is "sequentially sorted" `<space>':I....uy`, `<space>aeg....uy`, `<space>egi....ty`, `<space>iloty`, `<space>lt`, `<space>`, `<space>`,`<space>`, `<space>`.

It might be easier to visualize this if we use a string with digits in it. The string `111222334` will when "sorted" be: `123412312`.

### Challenge:

To no surprise, the challenge is to write a code that sorts a string according to the description above.

You can assume that the input string will contain only printable ASCII-characters in the range 32-126 (space to tilde).

---

**Test cases:**

```
**Test cases:**
 *:Tacest*es*s*

If you sort a string you'll typically get something like:
 ':Iacefghiklmnoprstuy aegilnorstuy egilosty iloty lt    

Hello, World!
 !,HWdelorlol

#MATLAB, 114 bytes
 #,14ABLMTbesty 1A

f=@(s)[mod(sort(cell2mat(cellfun(@(c)c+128*(0:nnz(c)-1),mat2cell(sort(s),1,histc(s,unique(s))),'un',0))),128),''];
'()*+,-0128:;=@[]acdefhilmnoqrstuz'(),0128@acefilmnorstu'(),12celmnostu'(),12celnstu(),clnst(),cls(),cs(),()()()()
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in *each language* counted in bytes will win<sup>[ref](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10132/31516)</sup>.

Comment: Title is a bit confusing, resulting in me thinking this and ignoring the description:
https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@1@td2jh4ZVe//@rW3kmJqempWdkZufk5uUXFBWXlFYqJKamZ@bk5UM4IHZ@cUmlApACkjklCgoKAA Nice challenge otherwise, I'll work on expanding that to meet the brief.

Comment: Can we output a list of characters instead of a string?

Comment: If you can input a string, then the output should be a string too. If a list of characters is the normal way of inputting and outputting strings in your languages then it's OK. You can for instance not output `{'S', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'r', 't'}` in Python, since the "normal" way to do it is `"String"`.

Comment: I'll correct my comment above: a string is a list of _characters_, so a list of characters is accepted output. However, a list of _strings_ is not accepted. This means, if it's possible to add a second character to an element in your list then it's not accepted. As an example: `{'a','b'}` is not accepted in Matlab since you can add a character to each of the characters like this: `{'aa','b'}`. Your input and output must be on the same format.

Comment: @StewieGriffin When you say sorted according to the description above. Do you mean my sort algorithm must follow the process of modifying ASCII values or it just has to produce the same output as that algorithm?

Comment: No, you only need the same result. So far, I think only one answer has used the same algorithm.

Comment: Proposed alternate title: `,Safginorst orst ort` :P

Comment: @DJMcMayhem haha, nice and descriptive title... It's actually possible to pronounce, so it could work :)

Comment: It would be funny if someone made an answer that was already sorted |:)

Answer (score 16):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
s.T.g
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s.T.g&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22%2a%2aTest+cases%3A%2a%2a%22%0A%22If+you+sort+a+string+you%27ll+typically+get+something+like%3A%22%0A%22Hello%2C+World%21%22%0A%22%23MATLAB%2C+114+bytes%22%0A%22f%3D%40%28s%29%5Bmod%28sort%28cell2mat%28cellfun%28%40%28c%29c%2B128%2a%280%3Annz%28c%29-1%29%2Cmat2cell%28sort%28s%29%2C1%2Chistc%28s%2Cunique%28s%29%29%29%2C%27un%27%2C0%29%29%29%2C128%29%2C%27%27%5D%3B%22&debug=0)

Very straightforward: Group and sort, transpose, concatenate.

```
s.T.g
s.T.gkQ    Implicit variables
   .gkQ    Group the input input lists of elements whose values match when the
           identity function is applied, sorted by the output value.
 .T        Transpose, skipping empty values. This puts all first characters into
           a list, then all second, etc.
s          Concatenate.
```

Comment: Pyth has everything to become new J, it's awesome

Comment: @shabunc If you want to see the new J, check out https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly

Answer (score 15):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ĠZị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#JYw/TsMwGMX3nOJDDLFdI9URAwqq1DKBBFsl1KIOwXVaC8eGfPYQRpYOvUQP0LFbx3KRcpFgq9v783uv/93Nz8dtfz4eTpu/n/2s7xmbKvQgK1RYMpY91dC5AOhaDxWgb7VdpSQ3Bnz3qWVlTAcr5SPSKL9OtdEfqswelTGOw6trzfIqu36ZTJ8nDxyEuIX3zivM6tGYIH1r3JKkeyLjoGiqi6iDJWMiqRyI4o6RYWntd7Q3gvKIFAm5rJBywdcavSTIg9VfQcWMUp4Hm/NhUvEh2nxx/w8)

#### How it works

Oh boy, this challenge was all but made for Jelly.

The *group* atom (`Ġ`) takes an array<sup>1</sup> as input and groups indices that correspond to identical elements of the array. The array of index groups is sorted with the corresponding elements as keys, which is precisely the order we require for this challenge.

Next, the *zip* atom (`Z`) transposes rows and columns of the generated (ragged) matrix of indices. This simply consists of reading the columns of the matrix, skipping elements that are not present in that column. As a result, we get the first index of the character with the lowest code point, followed by the first index of the character with the second lowest code point, … followed by the second index of the character with the lowest code point, etc.

Finally, the *unindex* atom (`ị`) retrieves the elements of the input array at all of its indices in the generated order. The result is a 2D character array, which Jelly flattens before printing it.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Jelly doesn't have a *string* type, just arrays of characters.</sub>

Comment: "Oh boy, this challenge was all but made for Jelly." -> 3 byte answer

Comment: As I said, almost made for Jelly. :)

Answer (score 10):

## Python 3, <s>109</s> <s>105</s> <s>104</s> <s>103</s> <s>99</s> <s>93</s> <s>90</s> <s>88</s> <s>81</s> <s>79</s> 69 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to FlipTack*

*7 bytes saved because flornquake caught my dumb error*

*2 bytes saved thanks to xnor*

*10 bytes saved thanks to Dennis*

```py
a=[*input()]
while a:
    for c in sorted({*a}):print(end=c);a.remove(c)
```

### Explanation

We start by converting our string to a list using a splat and storing that list in a variable `a`.  Then while our `a` is not the empty list we go through each unique member of `a` in sorted order, print it and remove a copy of that character from the list.

Each iteration prints thus prints one copy of each character present in `a`.

Comment: Why is `sorted` even needed here? `s=set(a)` results in a sorted set of unique characters right? Then shouldn't `list(s)` also be sorted? (I have tested, so I know it's not, I just don't understand why)

Comment: @StewieGriffin `set` is an unsorted set.

Comment: @StewieGriffin when printed they are sorted but not by their ASCII values exactly.  It often appears they are but I believe they are sorted by some type of hash.

Comment: I see, I'm reading about it now... :) A bit confusing, since `list` gets a different order back... Why not keep it consistent at least...

Comment: @WheatWizard If the loop body has constructs like `if`, `while`, `for`, etc, then it has to be on a newline. But if it's just a few statements, it can be written all on one line

Comment: You can make `f` a string instead of a list to save a few bytes.

Comment: @flornquake Thanks I should have seen that a while ago.

Comment: If you take `a=list(input())`, you can do `a.remove(c)`, which is a net savings.

Comment: Switching to Python 3 would save a lot of bytes. https://tio.run/nexus/python3#JY7NTsMwEITP9VMs4uAfDGoikFCqSC0nkOBWiUNVIeNsWgvHDrEDBMSzF5vcdmfnm1ntG4QaKKUnVe@Ecf0YGd@Tz6OxCKoii9YPoME4CH6I2LAfoX551Q/GRYauqTVfqasBO/@BTPNTSiIkMy@ZGZQ7ILvhKQe/UDOd6jhZzDQ/CbHFEEGrgKESgjy0MPnxvwkUhJhsh6xQayFOvdHK2gkOGJOlw3jMZ2vesCL3aK2X8OwH25yR86fN9nFzJ6EoruF1ihhIW69Z4LvONyzHM52AslPz0I6OrdP3@qIobwVbVs59p/Wy4DJZymyZqcBlIY8mRM2CHJ15HzFpnEs6OiqXeUoJaaX71R8

Comment: @Dennis Wow.  I tried a while ago and even with the fancy splats I could only save a byte.  Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, 44 bytes

```
import Data.List
concat.transpose.group.sort
```

Usage example:

```
Prelude Data.List> concat.transpose.group.sort $ "If you sort a string you'll typically get something like:"
" ':Iacefghiklmnoprstuy aegilnorstuy egilosty iloty lt    "
```

Sort, group equal chars to a list of strings (e.g. `"aabbc"` -> `["aa","bb","c"]`), transpose and flatten into a single string, again.

Comment: This might be stupid thing to ask but how does this adds 128,256,384.... to the repeated values?

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 75 bytes

```python
lambda s:`zip(*sorted((s[:i].count(c),c)for i,c in enumerate(s)))[1]`[2::5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#JY9PT8MwDMXP9FMYcahTAlorJqGgSRsnkOA2iUOptixNt4g0Kfkj1H35kWg3P/v3nu0BVvB90Xw89Bw825/VhJW3Lsge0bdMdY/CRhNQECrIYB0oKkAZkCaO0vEg0RNC2rrbtw1jy@6SmV0mHDdHiUvCipvJKRNgQMf/dspMMSAhl6raSh9AcC89q6rifYDZRsjLId0SkueYO6XWEOZJCa71DEcZEjLKcMpjrX4kK96k1pbCl3W6vy3uPjfbj80rhbp@gsMcpC@G1Tqd2Y62xxyPIhmakV@LIRpcp//Efd08V7hgxpyTfKgJTUiTkavLE1rTk/JBoKfRqN94fZ6W0ZR0kauUkGTZvfwD)

Comment: Don't know if it's valid but ``lambda s:`[sorted((1e9+s[:i].count(c),c)for i,c in enumerate(s))]`[18::21]`` works for strings with max length `9e9`.

Comment: @xnor you can drop the `[]` and change `18` to `17` to save two bytes.  `lambda s:\`sorted((1e9+s[:i].count(c),c)for i,c in enumerate(s))\`[17::21]`

Comment: @xnor At the very least, this should be a valid 32-bit Python golf. I tried to get rid off the `zip`, but I don't think adding `1e9` would have ever occurred to me... Thanks!

Comment: @WheatWizard Good eye. Thanks!

Comment: This fails if the string has backslashes in it.

Comment: @Lynn Right, rollang back. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>21</s> 20 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
t[0~⍨∊⍉(⊂⍋∪t)⌷⊢⌸t←⍞]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94H9JtEHdo94Vjzq6HvV2ajzqanrU2/2oY1WJ5qOe7Y@6Fj3q2VHyqG3Co955sSD1/xXAoIDLM02hMr9UoTi/qEQhUaG4pCgzLx0kop6To1BSWZCZnJiTU6mQnloCVJKbWpIBks7JzE61AgA)

`t[`...`]` index *t* (to be defined shortly) with...

`0~⍨` zeros removed from

`∊` the enlisted (flattened)

`⍉` transposed

`(⊂`…`)⌷` reordered using…

`⍋` the indices which would sort

`∪` the unique letters of

`t` *t* (to be defined shortly)

`⊢⌸t` keyed* *t*, which has the value of

`⍞` prompted text input

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2359%u2190%27If%20you%20sort%20a%20string%20you%27%27ll%20typically%20get%20something%20like%3A%27%20%u22C4%20t%5B0%7E%u2368%u220A%u2349%28%u22A2%u2338t%29%5B%u234B%u222At%u2190%u2359%3B%5D%5D&run)

---

* <sup>`⊢⌸t` creates a table where the rows (padded with zeros for a rectangular table) list each unique letters' indices in *t*.</sup>

Comment: which of the glyphs are more expensive?

Comment: @ren Updated to use new technology that allows counting each glyph as a single byte.

Answer (score 4):

## C, <s>109</s> <s>106</s> <s>105</s> <s>104</s> <s>102</s> <s>100</s> <s>97</s> <s>98</s> <s>96</s> 91 Bytes

<s>Back up to 98 Bytes, needed to initialize j to make f(n) re-useable</s>

<s>Down to 96 Bytes using puts in place of strlen B-)</s>

It's strange I had to back to strlen but I got rid of the for(;i++;) loop so now it's down to 91 Bytes.  Apparently the man page for puts reads;

```
"RETURNS
   If successful, the result is a nonnegative integer; otherwise, the result is `EOF'."
```

... I was lucky it was working in the first place

```
char*c,i,j;f(m){for(j=strlen(m);j;++i)for(c=m;*c;c++)if(*c==i){*c=7,putchar(i),j--;break;}}
```

test code...

```
main(c,v)char**v;
{
    char test[] = "If you sort a string you'll typically get something like: ";
    char test2[] = "Hello, World!";

    f(test);puts("");    
    f(test2);puts("");    
}
```

Here are a few test cases, now it's time to golf this down

```
C:\eng\golf>a.exe
 ':Iacefghiklmnoprstuy aegilnorstuy egilosty iloty lt
 !,HWdelorlo
```

Comment: Are the trailing spaces left out in the first test case?

Comment: I have three trailing spaces in the first test case...  That's because I didn't include the trailing space on the input string ;-)

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>68</s> <s>60</s> 59 bytes

```
Split[Characters@#~SortBy~ToCharacterCode]~Flatten~{2}<>""&
```

Accepts a String. Outputs a String.

**If list of characters were allowed (46 bytes):**

```
Split[#~SortBy~ToCharacterCode]~Flatten~{2,1}&
```

**Version using `Sort` (40 bytes):**

```
Split@Sort@Characters@#~Flatten~{2}<>""&
```

This version cannot be my answer because `Sort` cannot be used here; `Sort` sorts by canonical order, not by character code.

Comment: I don't know mathematica so this might be just fine, but did you read [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/106387/sort-a-string-sort-of/106408#comment258697_106387) comment?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Welp, nope. I can fix that, but doesn't that give an unfair advantage to languages that don't have a String vs Char[] distinction? [Related meta discussion](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2214/60043)

Comment: Good point. I made a correction, see the comment below the original. Fair? I'm not sure if this makes your answer valid or not.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Mathematica doesn't have a distinction between characters and strings. Even the `Characters` command technically output  a list of length-1 strings.

Comment: @StewieGriffin [I think this is also relevant](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10003/61980). I think it's better to allow the input in any reasonable format, be it a string, list of length 1 strings, array of characters, array of bytes, etc.

Comment: Wow, I had no clue that this usage of `Flatten` exists.

Comment: @MartinEnder [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/35945) is a good guide.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 79 bytes

```js
f=s=>s&&(a=[...new Set(s)]).sort().join``+f(a.reduce((s,e)=>s.replace(e,``),s))
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Works by extracting the set of unique characters, sorting it, removing them from the original string, and recursively calculating the sort of the rest of the string. 81 byte solution that I found interesting:

```
f=s=>s&&(s=[...s].sort().join``).replace(r=/(.)(\1*)/g,"$1")+f(s.replace(r,"$2"))
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```python
d={}
def f(c):d[c]=r=d.get(c,c),;return r
print`sorted(input(),key=f)`[2::5]
```

Takes a quoted string as input from stdin.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FYxBCsMgEEX3OcWQTRUki0I3Fg/QM4RAgo6pxBox40JKz251@/77rxr1/Q0GLVimuTSzXlRSZtqRmBaai2dCyilAGmJygdbrTISGuRAzMS4OLMrydb5L@VhqHV8WypmhW7DBRe2zd3LzHqhEpzfvC7R6Uz5I7z57d6Ac6x8)

Comment: I think this isn't allowed because [functions have to be re-usable](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4940/20260). You could make it a program.

Comment: I really like this method, sorting with a function that mutates. The nesting of tuples is clever too.

Comment: @xnor Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

### [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
/:+/@(={:)\;"0]
```

This is a verb that takes and returns one string.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGuloG@lre@gYVttpRljrWQQ@z81OSNfIU1BPTExKSk5JRUI1f8DAA)

Miles saved a byte, thanks!

### Explanation

Nothing too fancy here: sort primarily by order of occurrence, secondarily by char value.

```
/:+/@(={:)\;"0]  Input is y.
          \      Map over prefixes:
  +/              Sum
    @(   )        of
      =           bit-array of equality
       {:         with last element.
                 This gives an array of integers whose i'th element is k
                 if index i is the k'th occurrence of y[i].
           ;     Pair this array
            "0   element-wise
              ]  with y
/:               and sort y using it as key.
```

Comment: I think you can save a byte moving summation to the outside of the parentheses `+/@(={:)\`

Comment: @Miles Oh yeah, because a train has infinite rank. Nice, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Brainf*ck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), <s>458</s> 226 bytes

```
,[>>>>>>,]<<<<<<[[-<<<+<<<]>>>[>>>[>>>>>>]<<<[>>--[<->--]<-<[>->+<[>]>[<+>-]<<[<]>-]>>.[[-]<]<<<[[>>>>>>+<<<<<<-]<<<]>>>>>>]>>>[>>>[>>>>>>]<<<[>>--[<->--]<-<[>->+<[>]>[<+>-]<<[<]>-]>>[-<+<+>>]<[->>+<<]<[<<<<<<]>>>]>>>]]<<<<<<]
```

[Try it online! - BF](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#pU/RDoIwDPwcNrca4MnoXPiPpg8GIZLAiA5e/Hm8Df7AJm2ut9612yz7HFZcDmZCNUgBy0ci0jsgETtCFUdoyRtU8eyMB@UYKoLwDBtxWXLIzW6fhrJzcvxjAa40oCBiyuYA@wY5nOX4kGxbf29U1DzNTxXnz6Labhzr6bGDfg2qUa1uTVVfTqq8hvBFS5W2GKnTyK6K2lb2NcSlVdGuYXivHTitbbGGwpYJwQFtIbcf)

## [Numberwang](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Numberwang_(brainfuck_derivative)), <s>262</s> 226 bytes

```
8400000087111111442111911170004000400000071114002241202271214020914070419027114170270034427171114400000091111112711170000007000400040000007111400224120227121402091407041902711417027004219190071420091171411111170007000771111117
```

[Try it online! - NW](https://tio.run/nexus/numberwang#pU/tCsIwDHyctVqhiYWuirD3EH9I3XAwO7TbH19@Xj/ewEDC5Zq7pFtrdI7WUg5jGNUhLVhTE5HeAZkNMaolRsvaoVptyGlQZKBiCI@wsZQlVe6KfRrKzsnxjwW40oGCyHA2BygbbHW29UN224ZLJ6K8vuaHiPNnEb6fJn7dCxjWIDrhpd8TtzuhTyF80R5IKoxwGimqKBWp5xgXL6Jaw/hee3BSqmYNjdIJwQFtczv/AA)

I put both of these here because they are identical code.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 83 bytes

```
for($s=count_chars($argv[1]);$s=array_filter($s);$c%=128)echo$s[++$c]--?chr($c):'';
```

Unfortunately you can't have `unset` in a ternary so I need to use the annoyingly long `array_filter`.
Use like:

```
php -r "for($s=count_chars($argv[1]);$s=array_filter($s);$c%=128)echo$s[++$c]--?chr($c):'';" "If you sort a string you'll typically get something like:"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>37</s> 36 bytes

Thanks @DJMcMayhem for the byte!

```
Í./&ò
dd:sor
Íî
òÍ¨.©¨±«©±À!¨.«©/±³²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@3@4V09f7fAmrpQUq@L8Iq7DvYfXcR3edLj30Aq9QysPrTi08dBqIL3xcIMiSATI1gcKbT606f9/zzSFyvxSBaCuEoVEheKSosy8dJCIek6OQkllQWZyYk5OpUJ6aglQSW5qSQZIOiczO9UKAA)

Not sure I like the regex at the end, but I needed to make the `ò` break somehow.

#### Explain

```
Í./&ò                    #All chars on their own line
dd:sor                   #Delete empty line, sort chars
Íî                       #Join all lines together s/\n//
òÍ¨.©¨±«©±À!¨.«©/±³² #until breaking s/\v(.)(\1+)\1@!(.+)/\3\2\1
```

Comment: `Íî` (or `:%s/\n//g`) is shorter than `VGgJ`

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, 70 bytes

```
f=lambda s,i=0,c='':s[i>>7:]and(s.count(c)>i>>7)*c+f(s,i+1,chr(i%128))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#RU27CoMwFN39iiCUJrWIFkqLoHtnx9IhjUm9NA/JvQ75ehunHjjLeW6mt9K9J8nwDH3T4ROG4dq9pJ841iqsnriaI4dDe7kLMWT3Jk5/pTI8F6tWbOCWEIlhwiKzRk1RqzUiBG/BAfG2yRDF2JcPw1JYGe75fEwR/GdXjtYySgsoaW1iH53XgtM077aFr@7KYslZYoaPYvsB)

This is very inefficient. The test link changes the `i>>7` to `i>>5` and sets the recursion limit to 10000. Assumes the inputs only has ASCII values up to 126.

Uses the div-mod trick to iterate through two loops: minimum counts `i/128` in the outer loop and ASCII values `i%128` in the inner loop. Includes a character `c` with the given ASCII value if the number of times it appears in the string is at least its minimum count.

The code uses a trick to simulate the assignment `c=chr(i%128)` so that it can be referenced in the expression `(s.count(c)>i>>7)*c`. Python `lambda`s do not allow assignment because they only take expressions. Converting to a `def` or full program is still a net loss here.

Instead, the function pushes forward the value `chr(i%128)` to the next recursive call as an optional input. This is off by one because `i` has been incremented, but doesn't matter as long as the string doesn't contain special character `'\x7f'` (we could also raise 128 to 256). The initial `c=''` is harmless.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `d`, 3 bytes

```
sĠ∩
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJkIiwiIiwic8Sg4oipIiwiIiwiSGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkISJd)

```
s   # Sort
 Ġ  # Group run lengths
  ∩ # Transpose
    # (d flag) take deep sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 68 bytes

```
{my \a=.comb.sort;[~] flat roundrobin |a.squish.map({grep *eq$_,a})}
```

I was a little surprised to find that there's no built-in way to group like elements in a list.  That's what the squish-map bit does.

Comment: I get "This Seq has already been iterated" unless I rename `a` to `@a` (+2 bytes). Also, `grep *eq$_,` can be written `grep $_,` (-3 bytes) since a string is a valid smart-matcher.

Comment: `{[~] flat roundrobin |.comb.classify(~*){*}.sort»[*]}` -- This variation is only 54 bytes.

Comment: @smis I don't see that error.  Maybe we're using different versions?  I'm on rakudo-star-2016.10.  Anyway, your solution puts mine to shame, you should post it as a separate answer.

Comment: I'm using a bleeding-edge Rakudo compiled from the main branch of the git repo this week. Anyway, I posted the `classify`-based solution as a separate answer now.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>77</s> 75 bytes

```js
s=>(a=[],x={},[...s].sort().map(c=>a[x[c]=n=-~x[c]]=(a[n]||'')+c),a).join``
```

Stable sorts the lexicographically sorted string by n<sup>th</sup> occurence

```js
F=s=>(a=[],x={},[...s].sort().map(c=>a[x[c]=n=-~x[c]]=(a[n]||'')+c),a).join``

const update = () => {
  console.clear();
  console.log(F(input.value));
};
input.oninput = update;
update();
```

```css
#input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" value="         ':Iaaceeefggghiiiiklllllmnnooooprrssstttttuuyyyy" length=99/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: `1+~~` is the same as `-~`.

Comment: @Neil Awesome thanks -2 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## FSharp, <s>194</s> <s>190</s> <s>170</s> <s>140</s> 133 bytes

```fs
let f=Seq.map
let(@)=(>>)
f int@Seq.groupBy id@f(snd@Seq.mapi((*)128@(+)))@Seq.concat@Seq.sort@f((%)@(|>)128@byte)@Array.ofSeq@f char
```

Using Seq instead of Array saves a couple of bytes

Defining a shorter name, and using another maps to avoid a `(fun ->)` block

It turns out F# can map a char to an in, so removing the shortened name of System.Text.Encoding.ASCII, and adding in another map saves me 20 bytes!

Returning a char array instead of a string, saves me 30 bytes!

I no longer need to make sure it's a string, saves me 7 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 54 bytes

```
{[~] flat roundrobin |.comb.classify(~*){*}.sort»[*]}
```

Explanation:

- `{  }`: A lambda that takes one argument -- e.g. `21211`.
- `.comb`: Split the input argument into a list of characters -- e.g. `(2,1,2,1,1)`.
- `.classify(~*)`: Group the characters using string comparison as the grouping condition, returning an unordered Hash -- e.g. `{ 2=>[2,2], 1=>[1,1,1] }`.
- `{*}`: Return a list of all values of the Hash -- e.g. `[2,2], [1,1,1]`.
- `.sort`: Sort it -- e.g. `[1,1,1], [2,2]`.
- `»[*]`: Strip the item containers the arrays were wrapped in due to being in the hash, so that they won't be considered as a single item in the following step -- e.g. `(1,1,1), (2,2)`.
- `roundrobin |`: Zip the sub-lists until all are exhausted -- e.g. `(1,2), (1,2), (1)`.
- `flat`: Flatten the result -- e.g. `1, 2, 1, 2, 1`.
- `[~]`: Concatenate it to get a string again -- e.g. `12121`.

(Credit for the `roundrobin` approach goes to [Sean's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106412/14880).)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
{.¡"ä"©¹g×«øJ®K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#ASkA1v//ey7CoSLDpCLCqcK5Z8OXwqvDuErCrkv//yoqVGVzdCBjYXNlczoqKg)
or as a
[Test suite](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#JYy7TsMwGIX3PMVPGWIbg@qIAQUhtUxct0odEENwndTCsSG/jWTgPZiRWBASM3PyYMFRt3P5zhnfX@LbUf85G75m/Xdsho/@Z/i76n@v@TgytlLoQVaosGQsu6whugDoOg8VoO@0baYkNwZ8fNKyMiZCo3xCWuW3U230oyqzC2WM47B2ndnsZfu3y9XN8pyDEMfwEL3CrD5bEKR3rduQ6Z7INCjaaifqYMmCSCoPRHHCyLy09jXZQ0F5QooJ2a2QcsG3Gr0kyIPVz0GljFKeB5vz@aTSQ7L5/ek/)

**Explanation**

```
{                # sort input
 .¡              # group by equal elements
   "ä"©          # push "ä" and store a copy in the register
       ¹g×       # repeat the "ä" input-nr times
          «      # concatenate the result to each string in the grouped input
           ø     # zip
            J    # join to string
             ®K  # remove all instances of "ä" in the string
```

10 of the 15 bytes are for getting around 05AB1E's way of handling zipping strings of different length.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
ΣTgO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zikHT/////e6YpVOaXKhTnF5UoJCoUlxRl5qWDRNRzchRKKgsykxNzcioV0lNLgEpyU0syQNI5mdmpVgA)

### Explanation

```
ΣTgO
   O Order
  g  group
 T   Transpose
Σ    join
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 71 bytes

```javascript
f=x=>x&&[...x].filter(k=c=>k[c]?![h+=c]:k[c]=1,h='').sort().join``+f(h)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYrdDoIgFIBfhbxQmMXWrRt23TMwNxmBoCdwcGr69BSX38@qvirr5He8hfgypVhxiPFoW8k5PyZuPaBJdBNajJvU0@MiXS/0NFQQ96sTXcd4jgkp42v0YZ57Sx0rOoYcwXCIC7W0eVpyxg@pI1EkY/JhqaYDIHjuXiuAkywG/8vboKsZ/GaGhrHyAw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Input as a character array, output as a string.

```
ü Õc
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&header=cQ&code=/CDVYw&input=IklmIHlvdSBzb3J0IGEgc3RyaW5nIHlvdSdsbCB0eXBpY2FsbHkgZ2V0IHNvbWV0aGluZyBsaWtlOiI)

```
ü Õc     :Implicit input of character array
ü        :Group & sort
  Õ      :Transpose
   c     :Flatten
         :Implicitly join & output
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 114 bytes

Separated with newline for clarity, not part of byte count:

```
s=>[...s].map(a=>(m[a]=-~m[a])*128+a.charCodeAt(),m={})
.sort((a,b)=>a-b).map(a=>String.fromCharCode(a%128)).join``
```

### Demo

```js
`**Test cases:**
 *:Tacest*es*s*

If you sort a string you'll typically get something like:
 ':Iacefghiklmnoprstuy aegilnorstuy egilosty iloty lt    

Hello, World!
 !,HWdelorlol

#MATLAB, 114 bytes
 #,14ABLMTbesty 1A

f=@(s)[mod(sort(cell2mat(cellfun(@(c)c+128*(0:nnz(c)-1),mat2cell(sort(s),1,histc(s,unique(s))),'un',0))),128),''];
'()*+,-0128:;=@[]acdefhilmnoqrstuz'(),0128@acefilmnorstu'(),12celmnostu'(),12celnstu(),clnst(),cls(),cs(),()()()()`.split`\n\n`.map(s=>(p=s.split`\n`,console.log(`${p[0]}\n\n${r=f(p[0])}\n\nmatch: ${r==p[1]}`)),
f=s=>[...s].map(a=>(m[a]=-~m[a])*128+a.charCodeAt(),m={}).sort((a,b)=>a-b).map(a=>String.fromCharCode(a%128)).join``)
```

Comment: The same bytecount as my Matlab code, and the exact same approach. Haven't attempted to golf mine yet though. I'll probably upvote later if you add an explanation :-) (I've made a principle out of not upvoting answers without explanations, even when I understand it) :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 79 bytes

```
#(for[V[(group-by(fn[s]s)%)]i(range 1e9)k(sort(keys V))c[(get(V k)i)]:when c]c)
```

An anonymous function, returns a sequence of characters. Supports up-to 10^9 repetitions of any characters, which should be plenty.

Answer (score 0):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 24 bytes

```
O`.
O$#`(.)(?=(\1)*)
$#2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@@@foMflr6KcoKGnqWFvqxFjqKmlyaWibPT/v2eaQmV@qUJxflGJQqJCcUlRZl46SEQ9J0ehpLIgMzkxJ6dSIT21BKgkN7UkAySdk5mdaqUAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 59+1 = 60 bytes

Adds one byte for the `-n` flag. Port of @PatrickRoberts' dictionary solution.

```
d={};print *$_.chars.sort_by{|c|d[c]||=0;c.ord+128*d[c]+=1}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 6 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
∾·⊒⊸⊔∧
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oi+wrfiipLiirjiipTiiKcKCj7ii4jiiJhGwqgg4p+oCiAgIioqVGVzdCBjYXNlczoqKiIKICAiSWYgeW91IHNvcnQgYSBzdHJpbmcgeW91J2xsIHR5cGljYWxseSBnZXQgc29tZXRoaW5nIGxpa2U6IgogICJIZWxsbywgV29ybGQhIgogICIjTUFUTEFCLCAxMTQgYnl0ZXMiCiAgImY9QChzKVttb2Qoc29ydChjZWxsMm1hdChjZWxsZnVuKEAoYyljKzEyOCooMDpubnooYyktMSksbWF0MmNlbGwoc29ydChzKSwxLGhpc3RjKHMsdW5pcXVlKHMpKSksJ3VuJywwKSkpLDEyOCksJyddOyIK4p+p)

sort, group by occurrence count, join.

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `grouping.extras`, 48 bytes

```factor
[ natural-sort [ ] group-by values round-robin ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVDLTsMwEBTXfsVSDnngoKbiUKVCarkAEiAhijhUObiu01o4dvADERBfwqUX-AD-Br6GTV0kfPHM7Myudt8_K8qcNpufvZu724vrswKsNk6oFayM9g2CI_7sDLVArdXMguWPnivG_6E_h9DQGO5c2xihHIx7rz3A10_TGbcOGLXcFmnaD-pFBa3223FAwTrTDUUlkhKwhWBUyhZW3KGl5m7dlaV44MUuf86l1ATutZHL_Z12cDWdXU5PCeT5MSxax-2uUJ1MYpvMa72Mu4Exw_CwpgFUXsWTmCXsMB-O0nhQKPWCNMsTgpZhZwkpm5CcrIV1LLbEK4H7o5YkJPIqIoMOYQekUTnu994-vKuy0fdgDoo6b6jMtsvOoQzHzRYtPFHp8ZZI1TIzeiEUlCH3VdMGveGWJXDK1qGw2YT_Fw)

- `natural-sort` Sort the input
- `[ ] group-by values` Group like contiguous elements, e.g. `"aabbc"` -> `{ "aa" "bb" "c" }`
- `round-robin` One from each group in order, until there are no elements left. e.g. `{ "aa" "bb" "c" }` -> `"abcab"`